# how to calculate head to head stats using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to calculate head to head stats when two teams play against each other. Team1 can play against Team2 multiple times through out the season. Everytime there is a head to head match(game) I record the results i n the head to head table. Below is  my table schema  that holds the data:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'match up id',
`team1_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id of team1',
`team2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id of team2',
`winner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'winner(team ID) of this head to head',
`dateplayed` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date played',
`tournament_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'tournament name',
```

My goal is to be able to  calculate how many wins did team1(team1_id) had against team2(team2_id).
The query I am using now is:

```
SELECT  count(winner)as wins, te.id FROM head_to_head hh
    LEFT JOIN teams te ON
    hh.winner = te.id
    WHERE hh.team1_id ='225' AND
    hh.team2_id ='4'
    group by te.id
    order by count(winner)
```

If I use the query above i only get the "wins" for the hh.team2_id('4'). If they played against  each 5 time during the season  I want to be able to calculate team1 won 'x' amount of times and team2 won 'x' amount of times.So the end result should look like this:
--Assuming they played 5 times against each other during the season.

```
[team_id] [Wins]
   225      3
    4       2
```

Any help is great appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: So, you need `select winner, count(*) from head_to_head group by winner;`?

Comment: thank you Gurwinder. that seems to work fine.  I need one small addition. one of the team does not have any wins how can I set the count to zero  along with the teamID associated with it. thank you.

Comment: I know this wasn't your question, but i've built tables like this before and my suggestion to make this easier long term is to normalize out the competitors to a separate table.  Your parent table has game information, the participant table has a foreign key for the game and the team, you have a column that indicates win/loss, if it's a factor, you can have a column for home/away, and other participant specific data you want.  I've found that it's much easier to write queries that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  t.id team_id,
  count(h.winner) wins
from teams t
  left outer join
head_to_head h
  on t.id = h.winner
  and h.team1_id ='225'
  and h.team2_id ='4'
group by t.id;
```

Comment: it complains in the (h.*). Error 1064.

Comment: @user1960170 try now

Comment: It works but  it shows rows for all the teams  in my team's table. How can I only show two rows(for team_ID 225 and 4).

Comment: I added the WHERE condition and got what i was looking for.  thank for your help. Accepting your answer.

Comment: Sorry one last comment.If  the team2 didn't win any match how can i display in the results the total wins of team1  and team 2 showing 0(zero) wins